# run $(python -c "print 'AAAA'") not working

Tags: windows, shell

It behaves like I have given "$(python") to the argument.
It should behave like AAAA in argument, which it does not.
That is why I am unable to use shell code.
I want python output as the argument of run.

$() is now working. what is the alternative or Does it works in windows?

Comment: "It behaves like I have given "$(python") to the argument". What does that mean exactly? Please provide a [mcve] including expected output and actual output.

Comment: Are you running `run $(python -c "print 'AAAA'")` in a shell, or is that part of a `C` program?  Why is this tagged `C`.  IOW, what are you asking?

Comment: I want AAAA as the argument but I donta want to use `run AAAA`

Comment: I am debugging a c program

Comment: I want python to give arguments to run in gdb

Comment: this is my C program I am using windows 10 `#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void overflow(){
 printf("%s\n","Execution Hijacked");
}
void function(char *str){
 char buffer[5];
 strcpy(buffer, str);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 function(argv[1]);
 printf("%s\n","Executed Normally");
 return 0;
}`

Comment: I used `gdb overflow.exe` and getting `(gdb)` prompt.

Comment: Ah: I would suggest running the python script to generate data in a .gdbinit

Comment: William I am a beginner what is .gdbinit. I think you are telling me to write to a file named .gdbinit. will the content of this file work as a command line argument in run

Comment: Yes, if you put a file named .gdbinit with the contents `set args foo bar`, it will set the arguments to 'foo bar'.  So you could do `python -c 'print "set args AAAA"' > .gdbinit`

Comment: william `(gdb) shell python -c 'print "set args AAAA"' > .gdbinit <br />
  File "<string>", line 1
    'print
         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
python -c 'print "set args AAAA"' > .gdbinit exited with status 1`

Answer (score 0):

GDB's "run" command doesn't do shell expansion - it will pass the arguments `$(python`, `-c`, `"print` and so on.

However, you can start GDB with:

```
gdb --args ./yourprogram $(python -c "print 'AAAA'")
```

and then run:

```
run
```

Comment: `
E:\\Scripts>gdb --args ./overflow.exe $(python -c "print 'AAAA'")
(gdb) break 8
(gdb) break 9
(gdb) run
Breakpoint 1, function (str=0x84222c "$(python") at overflow.c:8
8        strcpy(buffer, str);
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
Breakpoint 2, function (str=0x84222c "$(python") at overflow.c:9
9       }
(gdb) x/16wd $esp
0x29fed0:       2752235 8659500 2752248 2752460
0x29fee0:       1964364240      -836496046      620756990       1954115624
0x29fef0:       7237480 4200656 2752280 4199296
0x29ff00:       8659500 88      20      68
(gdb)`

Comment: it must be `Breakpoint 1, function (str=0x8c2224 "AAAA") at overflow.c:8
8        strcpy(buffer, str);`

Comment: @YashGulati Oh, you're using Windows? The whole `$()` thing only works in bash (and similar shells). You could try Cygwin, maybe.

Comment: what could be the windows alternative in cmd?

Comment: @YashGulati: the `for /F` command can be used this way, at least for simple cases.  But batch language isn't really designed for complicated tasks.  Consider using Powershell or, well, in your case, why not use Python?

Comment: in cygwin `(gdb) "E:\Scripts\ooo.exe": not in executable format: File format not recognized
` <br /> I recompiled using gcc of cygwin, which is making .exe.